# Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart

After the update, I started to get such an error, there was no problem before the update, the application builds but does not open

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:49183/dart_sdk.js:5391:11)
at Object.castError (http://localhost:49183/dart_sdk.js:5348:15)
at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:49183/dart_sdk.js:5680:17)
at dart.LegacyType.new.as (http://localhost:49183/dart_sdk.js:7335:60)
at new module_model.ModuleModel.fromJson
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzQWA.png)

I'm new to Flutter and my english might be a bit bad, sorry for that, thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code that leads to this error.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to learn, the application was working before the update, I tested it after updating, it doesn't work, I didn't change anything, the error screen is here  [https://i.ibb.co/jv8YNDf/Ads-z.png]

Comment: that error appear because you have different type variable and you force it to set with different type. try print runtimeType of your variable before the error

Comment: I don't know much about this because I don't know much.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely instead of add a number you added the number with quotes.

**1 is a number**

**"1" is a string**

Try to see if that's your case.

Comment: I'm getting a very peculiar error and it happened by itself [https://i.imgur.com/WmDnoRy.png]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution, you can try it ->

```
int.parse(your_values)
```

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: Where you use your this value, cover with this: int.parse(value)

Comment: I couldn't solve

Comment: @rootcause please share your code so that we could help you with a solution. If not the whole, atleast the area where the error occurs.

Comment: @Delwinn the problem is that there is no problem with the files, i open the unused file, still the same error and no solution works [i.imgur.com/WmDnoRy.png] or [i.ibb.co/jv8YNDf/Ads-z.png] It gave this error after the update and I couldn't find the solution anywhere

Comment: Try rebuilding the gradle project and delete cache files

Comment: I did it, still the same problem, can you connect to the computer with anydesk? @Delwinn

Comment: I suppose that's against TOS of StackOverflow... Why don't you share your code here?

Comment: I don't know which code to share I'm new to flutter